# Adding file to git Ignore in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gitignore

I'm working on making the flutter app and I'm trying to add my "key.properties" file, which includes passwords, into git ignore file. In my android/.gitignore file, I wrote

```
gradle-wrapper.jar
/.gradle
/captures/
/gradlew
/gradlew.bat
/local.properties
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
/key.properties
```

like this and I thought it makes key.properties file ignored on my git hub, but when I push the code, I still can see it on GitHub. Is the way I write correct??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you added the key.properties line to .gitignore after that file had been committed.

What you need to do is the following:

git rm --cached key.properties

`**/android/key.properties` should be added to .gitignore!

Answer (score 4):

Adding file in .gitignore there is some step

---

**If file is not exist in folder**

1) then create file then add into .gitignore

---

**If file is already exist so you want to add in .gitignore**

1) delete file (Before backup)

2) commit deleted file.

3) add file name into .gitignore

4) commit .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

If there is any good method to try, It's [gibo](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/gibo)  (.gitgnore boilerplates)

**Usage:**

```
 gibo dump Archives Backup Android Dart DartEditor Emacs Gradle Java JetBrains Jenv Kotlin Linux macOS Maven Objective-C SublimeText Vim VisualStudioCode Windows Xcode >> .gitignore
```

Many would argue its output is overkill.

**Check** this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13892) for some ideas.